# Gluing two continuous map in a certain condition

Tags: general-topology, continuity

Let $A \subset X$ ,  $f : A\times I \to Y$ , $g :X \times \{0\} \to Y$ be two continuous maps with the same image on $A \times \{0\}$, where $I = [0,1]$.

In this situation, can I construct a continuous map $h: A\times I \cup X \times \{0\} \to Y$ by gluing $f$ and $g$ ?

If $A$ is a closed subset, it is right.

In general case, however, I don't know for sure.

If not, please suggest a counterexample.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not in general, here is a sketch of a counterexample. Take $X=[0,1]$, $A=(0,1)$. Consider a continuous function on $A\times[0,1]$ that takes value $0$ on the complement of a small open subset containing the points $(1/n,1/n)$ and value $n$ at $(1/n,1/n)$, let this be $f$, and let $g$ be $0$ on $X$.

Comment: That's a good counterexample. Thank you.